# Memory check without rebooting?

Tags: uefi, ram, memtest

I picked up a laptop at the flea market.  Seems to be Chinese product for internal market. It had Windows Starter that didn't even boot at all. I installed Linux and found out that its motherboard can't boot in non-UEFI mode at all. So no LiveCDs.  In UEFI, there in no memstest86+. 
How can I ran some memory check of this machine, short of disassembling it and plugging memory somewhere else??? Windows can run memory tests after booting, can we?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `memtester`. It's in the repositories (at least, for 14.04, which I happen to have running at the moment).

Alternatively, you could try [`memtest86` for EFI.](http://www.memtest86.com/download.htm)

Comment: memtester is a strange tool, really. It can test only some amount of memory which is not in use by the system... What's the point?