# Is my SSD broken?

Tags: boot, partitioning, hardware, ssd

I recently started experiencing lags and freezes on Windows 10. Because of that, I've removed it and have tried installing various Linux distributions (Ubuntu, Debian, Linux Mint). With all of them I experienced familiar freezes, and sometimes after I rebooted the PC it became stuck, so I had to force reboot (cut power and turn it on). Then this message popped up: [boot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPPP8.jpg)

The SSD is 840 EVO by Samsung.
Also, when freezing began (still windows 10, samsung software magician) I've tried to disable RAPID mode, and while doing that PC froze again.
Is there any way to fix the ssd ?

Edit: pluged ssd out and in again, booted into live cd, fixed it with fix disk commands and then everything started working perfectly. That was until few hours ago, when very weird thing started happening: everything is stable up until I go to a website called aliexpress and click on my order pc screen turns black and sound freezes (is repeating 1 s over and over again).

Answer (score 1):

The boot error screen shot you've shown indicates filesystem damage exists on one of your partitions. That's not surprising after a system crash; whenever the system shuts down uncleanly, the filesystem will be left in an inconsistent state and a disk check will be performed, even if the cause was not disk-related. If I had to bet, I'd put money on bad RAM, based on your description; but it could be a failing CPU, a bad hard disk, a failing motherboard, or something else. Failures like the one you describe can also be caused by bad drivers, although the fact that you ran into similar crashes in two OSes suggests a hardware failure.

You can test some of these components with specialty tools such as [GNOME Disk Utility or `smartctl`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04) to check the SMART status of the hard disk, or [memory check tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434983/memory-check-without-rebooting) to test your RAM.

If your hardware is failing, it's very unlikely that you'll be able to fix it, just replace the failing component. (There are some exceptions for trivial problems like loose cables.)

- If it's the disk that's going bad, you have the added complication of transferring data off the failing disk, which can sometimes be difficult because of the very failure you're trying to overcome.
- If your RAM is going bad, and if you have more than one memory module, you might be able to remove the bad one and leave the good one in place. Of course, that means you'll be halving the amount of RAM in your system (assuming you've got two equal-sized memory modules). Some systems have just one memory module, though, so if it's going bad, you must replace the whole thing.